# Code.org's AppLab readRecords function problem

Tags: app-lab

I call readRecords on line 74 and the syntax is simple, but the program hangs at this line. The Students table exists, with 12 students, it was originally created with the createRecord on line
60. I've looked at the syntax for this line for tooooo long. What am I missing?

Also, is there a more elegant way to use this data outside of the readRecords code block? I'm copying it to arrays (no 2-dimensional arrays or structures in applab). I tried to create a global 'records' of some kind, without success. The App Lab project examples I learned from use the data within the readRecords code block, but not outside the block.

The project:
my project: https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/xEEOqp8zpOJ2g-YyCntajlhvh0crb2ysLvP1Pg5LCF8

The specific code:

```
    onEvent("choosePeriodNext", "click", function() {
        var chosenPeriod = getText("period2");
        readRecords("Students", {}, function(records) {
            numStudents = records.length;
            if (numStudents>0) {
                for (var i =0; i < numStudents; i++) {
console.log (records[i].goesBy);
                goesBys[i] = records[i].goesBy;
                pronounss[i] = records[i].pronouns;
                periods[i] = records[i].period;
                firsts[i] = records[i].first;
                lasts[i] = records[i].last;
                games[i] = records[i].game;
                jobs[i] = records[i].job;
                goodAts[i] = records[i].goodAt;
                toKnows[i] = records[i].toKnow;
                photos[i] = records[i].photo; 
            }
        learnNames();    
        } else setScreen ("home");
    });  
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Carol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.

I found that this code worked in a collegue's browser, but not mine.

I cleared cache and cookies, then restarted my browser. Now it works.

Oh my.